# How to break lines properly which contain both CJK and english characters in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, linefeed

I found that CJK article in my wordpress4.7 can't break  lines properly,which contain both CJK and english characters.
Here is the article before publish.

[image]

All the lines breaked properly before publish.

[image]

Now it displayed as below after published.
All lines messed ,breaked bad-formatted as unexpected way.

[image]

I had tried to fix it this way.

```
vim  /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css 
.site-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1320px;
    position: relative;
}

.site-content {
    word-wrap: break-word;overflow:hidden;
    word-break:break-all;white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

To restart  apache and wordpress,no effect at all.
My wordpress version is 4.7,theme is twentysixteen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this code in your functions.php theme file

```
    function my_tinymce_fix( $init )
    {
        // html elements being stripped
        $init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'div[*], article[*]';

        // don't remove line breaks
        $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false;

        // convert newline characters to BR
        $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true;

        // don't remove redundant BR
        $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;

        // pass back to wordpress
        return $init;
    }
    add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tiny_mce_fix');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try word press plugin.
[TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)

There is option to disable automatically remove of br tag and p tag from setting page of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Don't Muck My Markup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dont-muck-my-markup/)

**Don't Muck My Markup** is a plugin that will allow you to

> disable all auto-generated HTML markup from your posts and pages on a **page-by-page basis**.

It adds a small box **in the default WordPress editor** to **turn off** *automatic markup / formatting* **for that page/post**

This means that can keep all other pages the same and just disable the automatic formatting only for the *page / post you're currently editing*

Then,

when you have a page/post with mixed content, disable the automatic formatting for that page/post and manually add html mark up like `<h1> <br> <hr> <p>` and so on